# How to add the snmpv3 context name if using TableUtils.getTable in snmp4j

Tags: snmp4j

In `snmp4j version 2.0.2`, I'm using `TableUtils.getTable` to get the snmp info,

and I'm using `usm.adduser` to add all the profiles,

but I don't see a way to add the context name of the v3profile.

I know you can set the `ScopePDU.setContextName`, but `TableUtils.getTable` don't use PDU
object,

unless I'm missing something, please help...

Thanks,
Julie

Answer (score 0):

I got the response back from Frank in the gmane.network.snmp4j.general newsgroup, basically just need to create a subclass of PDUFactory in order to specify the context name there.